# Make html element stay in place when scrolled past

Tags: javascript, html, css

How does one make an html element not become fixed until it has been scrolled to? So while the user is scrolling it will be in normal position, but it won't go out of the screen after the user has scrolled past it?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a listener to the `onscroll` event, and if the `scrollTop` is greater than the element's Y position, set it to `position: fixed`.

Comment: window.onscroll doesn't seem to work. It just triggers whenever I load the page, but not when I scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this code before:

http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2011/08/07/how-to-fix-element-position-after-some-scroll-using-jquery/

```
(function($){
        $.fn.scrollFixed = function(params){
        params = $.extend( {appearAfterDiv: 0, hideBeforeDiv: 0}, params);
        var element = $(this);

        if(params.appearAfterDiv)
            var distanceTop = element.offset().top + $(params.appearAfterDiv).outerHeight(true) + element.outerHeight(true);
        else
            var distanceTop = element.offset().top;

        if(params.hideBeforeDiv)
            var bottom = $(params.hideBeforeDiv).offset().top - element.outerHeight(true) - 10;
        else
            var bottom = 200000;                

            $(window).scroll(function(){    
                if( $(window).scrollTop() > distanceTop && $(window).scrollTop() < bottom )         
                    element.css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'5px'});
                else
                    element.css({'position':'static'});             
            });           
        };
    })(jQuery);
```

Then just call the elements:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
$("#scrollingDiv").scrollFixed({appearAfterDiv:'.sidebar p', hideBeforeDiv:'.footer'});
$("#scrollingDiv1").scrollFixed({hideBeforeDiv:'.footer'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [jQuery Scrollfollow plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-follow/). I have used this to achieve that effect conveniently.

You simply call it on the element that you want to stay in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( '#example' ).scrollFollow();
</script>
```

Easing, position and other parameters can be configured.

Comment: I downloaded that zip, but the code is doing nothing. I added a <script> with "src='jquery.scrollfollow.js'" to the html file, but nothing happened. Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: Please read the usage instructions of the plugin: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-scroll-follow/wiki/Usage It depends on jQuery (wow) and jQueryUI Core.